# Test if double is integer

Tags: c++, integer, double

Is there a better way to test if a double has decimal digits than this?

```
double value = 7.2;
bool isInt = value == double(round(value));
```

BTW: I use C++ 11 and gcc **AND** MSVC2015

Comment: Better in terms of what?

Comment: The problem with floating point numbers is that what you think is `9.0` (for example) might actually not be. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for some details.

Comment: This is why i ask. I think it won't work for every number. But i can't figure out which one

Comment: Just to highlight points from the duplicate: [`modf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf), [`trunc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc).

Comment: thx, i use the solution from the other question.